# Building a 'universe' in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to build a 'universe' where my colleagues and I can see the following:

```
REPORTNAME - DATASET(S) - DATASOURCE
```

For each I want to know details:

```
REPORTNAME - which parameters? what kind? caching enabled?
DATASET - underlying Query, resulting Columns
DATASOURCE - COnnectionstring
```

Getting a list of reports is done (through queries on Reportserver database)

Getting the details for the datasources too (script executed against webservice with rs.exe)

But where do I find the information regarding the datasets? I cannot find anything in the tables/views in the reportserver database, nor can I find any infor regarding the datasets in the documentation with the webservice. Who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
henro

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3148/sql-server-reporting-services-xml-data-source-and-data-set/ looks promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you can't find any information regarding the data sets in the report server database makes me think that you're looking for information on in-report (local) data sets. If you were dealing with shared data sets, you would have found them when you looked in the [Catalog (type = 8) and DataSets tables](http://sornanara.blogspot.com/2011/05/ssrs-reportserver-database-tables.html).

In-report (local) data set details are contained in the report's definition (RDL XML) under /Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query.

You can query the local data set information out of the report server database, using the XML data type's functions to pivot each data set's details into its own result set row:

```
SELECT ReportItemID = ItemID,
        DataSetName = QueryXml.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR(256)'),
        DataSourceName = QueryXml.value('(*:Query/*:DataSourceName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(260)'),
        CommandType = QueryXml.value('(*:Query/*:CommandType)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(15)'),
        CommandText = QueryXml.value('(*:Query/*:CommandText)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
             ContentXml = (CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content)))
        FROM Catalog
        WHERE Type = 2
    ) AS Data
        CROSS APPLY ContentXml.nodes('/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet') QueryData(QueryXml)
```

While you're at it, you could query [all the details needed](http://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2014/08/07/3278/ssrs-auditing-report-queries)  for your report out of the report server database, eliminating the need to use the Report Server web service/rs.exe *(disclosure: link is to an article on my blog)*.

Comment: Well,   actually, I am talking about shared datasets. I can find them in catalog but what I need are the contents: the fieldnames and the commandtext. I cannot find those (is that because they are encrypted?).  Your example no 5 looks promising but it does not give me any results on SQL2008, 2008R2, 2012 or 2014.

Comment: Apologies, the second link had everything I need!

Comment: Ben, your second link was exactly what I needed. One question though: It retu8rns the commandtext of the datasets but is there a way to retrieve the fields from that comandtext?

Comment: You can get the fields by looking in the XML under *:DataSets for *:Fields.

Comment: Ben, I am not totally sure how to do that: Would this have to be added? Fields AS (
    -- Details on queries used in reports.
    /* Outputs one row per query used in each report. */
    SELECT ItemID,
        Datafield = QueryXml.value('(*:Datafield)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(260)')
    FROM CatalogWithXml
        CROSS APPLY ContentXml.nodes('/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet/*:Fields') QueryData(QueryXml)
), ?

Comment: @Henrov, do you want one field per row in the resultset (e.g. a dataset with three fields would be returned as three rows in the resultset)?

Comment: I actually already figured it out. Answer to your question: yes, that is what I am looking for. Thanx a lot for all of your help! You made some ppl really happy :)

Comment: Ben,

this code is wonderful, however, I do miss the shared datasources.
Have you come any further on this or could you help me to add shared datasets to this?

Friendly greetings, Henro